# does dropbox run smoothly and reliably with the unity desktop on ubuntu 16?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, mate, dropbox

i tried installing dropbox on kubuntu and it wasn't working very well, so i switched to ubuntu 16 (because dropbox was the first thing i tried to install so nothing to lose, and the dropbox website listed an "ubuntu" version of the software).

but apparently dropbox doesn't connect to the unity desktop on ubuntu 16? there's only packages available to go with gnome and mate?

there's a .deb file on the dropbox website, which is just listed as "ubuntu" and doesn't mention which desktop it goes with. But i've been told to ALWAYS use the package manager rather than downloading through a web browser, because the updates work better?

Comment: "smoothly", "reliably" - these are subjective terms. Opinion based questions are not allowed here. I would suggest you to change the question title to something like "how do I install Dropbox in Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity)?"

Comment: For installation I would suggest you to install from "Ubuntu Software" application. It installs the `nautilus-dropbox` package. Then when you run it it fetches proprietary package(s) from the Dropbox website and completes the installation. The process is mostly automated and straightforward. You'll just have to click a few buttons.

Comment: @pomsky but unity/ubuntu16 doesn't use nautilus?

Comment: Yes, it does. The application called *Files* (the default file manager) is Nautilus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files

Comment: but doesn't ubuntu 16 use unity desktop instead of gnome?

Comment: Yes, but Unity comes with many GNOME applications by default, Nautilus is one of them. So you'll need Nautilus integration for Dropbox.

Comment: I would suggest you to give it a go. If something goes wrong you can always ask a new question.